# Having issues unmounting partition for debian install

Tags: linux, debian, unmounting

I have a 50gb partition set up on my mac for installing debian, MS-DOS (FAT) format. I blessed it and am now unmounting it in order to copy the img file over. I'm using:
`$ diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk0s5` to unmount and am planning to then use: `$ sudo dd if=debian7.8.0-amd64-CD-1.img of=/dev/disk0s5 bs=1m` to copy the img file to the partition.

The problem is every time I try to execute the unmount on Term, it gives me `Unmount of disk0 failed: at least one volume could not be unmounted`. I've verified this is the right disk using `diskutil list`. Any ideas what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

At least one process (or the kernel itself with another mount) is using this volume. That may be an open file or just the current working directory.

If `/dev/disk0s5` is mounted to `/mnt/tmp` then run

```
fuser -vm /mnt/tmp
```

to find out which processes block the unmounting.

You find the right mountpoint (under Linux) by searching `/proc/mounts` for the block device:

```
grep ^/dev/disk0s5 /proc/mounts
```

Or you may use the command `mount`.

But I must admit that I ignored the point that Linux doesn't call it's drives `/dev/disk0s5` thus I guess you described what you did under MacOS. That would explain the different `fuser` behaviour.

Comment: I have a couple questions regarding this answer. First off, how can I check where `/dev/disk0s5` is mounted? Secondly, I tried using `fuser -vm /mnt/tmp`, and I got `Unknown option: k Unknown option: m
fuser: [-cfu] file ... -c file is treated as mount point -f the report is only for the named files -u print username of pid in parenthesis`. Suggestions?

Comment: @hohos6 I edited my answer. The problem seems to be that you describe MacOS and my answer describes Linux. You may better ask on the Mac site.

Comment: Haha ok. Thx for the help